# Need onclick event, making div fade out "THEN" deleting div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the code for the the div. All I need is for the div to fade out and then have the parent child removed after fade.

[**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGp62/)

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="fadeOut(this)" id="fadeOut">
    <div id="divText">
        This is a simple div with some text in it. This is another line of text.
        All I am doing is continuing adding text to my div container. If I keep adding text guess what will happen. You have to scroll to see the rest!
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is located in the JSFiddle link.

Comment: you want to remove fadeout or div text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicate `jQuery` via the tags, so here is a jQuery solution.  It passes a callback function to the `fadeOut` function which removes the `#divText`.

```
function fadeOut(i) {
    $(i).fadeOut(3000, function(){
        $("#divText").remove();
    });
}
```

One improvement I would recommend is to attach the event handler via javascript instead of inline.

**Javascript**

```
$("#fadeOut").click(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(3000, function(){
        $("#divText").remove();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fadeOut">
   <!--Content Here -->
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZGp62/1/

Answer (score 1):

I know solution for this at jQuery

```
$("#fadeout").ckick(function(){
$(this).find("div").fadeOut().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the fadeOut jquery function.

Example:

```
$( "#buttonID" ).click(function() {
    $( "#thedivID" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        //this removes the div from the DOM
        $( "#thedivID" ).remove();
    });
});
```

See more examples and documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/